# How to set a cron job to open a web page in the browser using crontab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cron

I use a website to order food, and I would like this website to be automatically opened in the browser at 11 am day.

I opened crontab using "crontab -e" and tried this:

```
59 10 1-31 1-12 SUN,MON,TUE,THU google-chrome --new-window http://food.com
```

and also tried this:

```
59 10 1-31 1-12 SUN,MON,TUE,THU x-www-browser http://food.com
```

But they sent me an email instead of opening the website:

```
(x-www-browser:16597): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
(google-chrome:16883): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Thanks!

---

**Update**: The solution was adding "export DISPLAY=:0 &&" to crontab. i.e.:

```
53 10 * 1-12 SUN,MON,TUE,THU export DISPLAY=:0 && google-chrome --new-window http://www.foodsite.com
```

Comment: Though I have nothing to add to the discussion, the idea of opening up a browser window at 11am as a reminder to order food is quite innovative!

Comment: Slightly more succinct version would be to not export and instead just prefix your command with the environment variable you want set: `DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome ...`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That error means that GTK cannot find where X is running. It might be your DISPLAY variable is not set in the context that cron is trying to call your job. Try adding

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

To your .bashrc file if DISPLAY isn't set already. To test, enter the command

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

in a terminal and see what is printed out.

Comment: Thanks Joshua.
When I type "echo $DISPLAY", I get ":0.0", 
which means the DISPLAY variable is set I think..

Comment: Edit: Hi Joshua, turns out that I had to add this in crontab instead of ~/.bashrc. See my update.

Comment: Ahh, I should have thought of that myself. Well done on figuring it out.